# How to run final stage on Azure Pipelines after all previous stages completed successfully

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline that receives a list of products and create stages dynamically per each product.
Currently each product create the final stage for its own but I would like to run the final stage once after all stages completed successfully.

```
parameters:
  - name: product
    type: object
  - name: component
    type: string
  - name: configuration
    type: string  

stages:
  - ${{ each product in parameters.product }}:
    - stage: ${{ product }}_build
      displayName: Build for ${{ product }}-${{ parameters.component }}
      dependsOn: [ ] # Force to run in parallel
      variables:
        Configuration: ${{ parameters.configuration }}
        Platform: ""
        ProductName: '${{ product }}'
        Component: '${{ parameters.component }}'
        ConfigurationVariant: ''
        SigningType: TestSigned
        FirmwareSigningType: Test
        ProjectFilePath: Project\SAM.eww

      jobs:
        - template: firmware/mcu.tpl.yml@BuildTemplate
          parameters:
            matrixAxis: 'ProductName,Configuration'
            enablePublish: true
            gitSubmoduleStrategy: 'PRAllRecursive'
            preInit:
              - checkout: git://MCU/${{ product }}-${{ parameters.component }}@master
                clean: true
                submodules: recursive
                persistCredentials: true
                path: s

    - template: firmware/rockton-fw-pr-test.stage.tpl.yml@BuildTemplate
      parameters:
        uniqueName: '${{ product }}_'
        dependsOn:
        - ${{ product }}_build
        enableAuthorization: true
        environment: 'Authorize PR tests'
```

I would like to take the last stage: ***firmware/rockton-fw-pr-test.stage.tpl.yml@BuildTemplate***

And run it once after all each loop stages completed successfully

Any idea how can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, move your final job *outside* of the loop. Right now, it's going to run for *every* iteration, not just once at the end.

Then change your `dependsOn` block to iterate over your parameters and define an entry for each job, something along these lines:

```
dependsOn: 
- ${{ each product in parameters.product }}:
  - ${{ product }}_build
```

Comment: Thanks!
I was almost there by myself... :-)